# Excel string calculation works...sometimes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've found lots of partial answers to this question but either I'm not implementing them correctly or they don't really match my problem. I have a column and in each cell there are two numbers separated by a colon. Each number can be one or two digits. (Examples: 1:1, 1:2, 12:10, 12:20, etc.) I need to query the cell and return one thing if the number to the left of the colon is smaller than the number on the right, and return something else if the number to the left is bigger than or equal to the number on the right. I have calculations to extract the numbers on each side of the colon:

```
=LEFT(E2,FIND(":",E2)-1)
```

and to the right of the colon:

```
=MID(E2,FIND(":", E2)+1,LEN(E2))
```

In this example, the numbers with the colon are in cell E2. I have another calculation to compare the two numbers and return the desired result:

```
=IF((LEFT(E2,FIND(":",E2)-1))<(MID(E2,FIND(":",E2)+1,LEN(E2))),"Divider, ","Combiner, ")
```

The idea is to return "Divider, " if the number to the left of the colon is smaller than the number to the right, and to return "Combiner, " if the number to the left is equal or larger.

What's frustrating me is that the calculations to extract the numbers on either side of the colon are working, and the calculation to determine which is bigger fails only when the first digit on the left side of the colon is smaller than the number on the right side, even if the left side number has a second digit and is therefore bigger. For example, for 12:3 it returns "Divider, " even though 12 is bigger than 3 and it should return "Combiner, ". But I know that it's seeing both digits of 12, because my equation to extract the left side number works.

Much appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.   --Dan Littman

Comment: This is done for diagnostics, and is not necessarily how it will be long term. Make 3 columns, Left, Right, Result. For both the left and right column add a =0+ in front of your formula. Then use the IF > for the result column.

Comment: Please accept a solution below. It turns out that either will work. Even adding the INT(LEFT...) as in INTeger will work. The reason yours is failing is because "1" and "01" are Strings in a alphabetizing. Try experimenting "1:11" works, but "2:11" fails. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is becuase LEFT,MID,RIGHT return a string and `"3"` is greater than `"12"` as text goes character by character.

You need to change the numbers to numbers,  the `--` does this:

```
=IF((--LEFT(E2,FIND(":",E2)-1))<(--MID(E2,FIND(":",E2)+1,LEN(E2))),"Divider, ","Combiner, ")
```

Comment: This isn't the first time I've seen the "--" being used and it totally baffles me. What is the explanation of the "--"? I know what a negation is, and a double negative or double negation, but in the sense of Excel or even more basic level even, I haven't a clue.

Comment: @ejbytes it is a short cut that returns the same as `VALUE()`.  by doing any type of mathematics on numbers that are text, the text will become number.  The `--` multiplies the number by -1 twice.  It could also be done with `1*` or `0+` it is just easier and faster to hit the `-` twice.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks! It's a "smart" reaction built into Excel, sort of like implied casting in programming languages. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `LEFT` and `MID` function calls in a `VALUE` call:

```
=IF((VALUE(LEFT(E2,FIND(":",E2)-1)))<VALUE((MID(E2,FIND(":",E2)+1,LEN(E2)))),"Divider, ","Combiner, ")
```